# Python - Define variables before try/catch or just let them bubble out?

Tags: python, exception

Coming from Java and C based languages, this looks odd in Python.  The `x` variable is defined in the try block but used outside of it.

I understand that python does not scope the try block though.

```
try:
    x = 5
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

print(f"x = {x}")
```

Is this considered to be good form in Python, or is it preferred to set, say, `x = None` beforehand? or some third option?  Why?

Comment: Thanks to the OP for introducing me to python f-strings

Answer (score 1):

There are very few situations where a `try: / except:` is really the appropriate thing to do. Obviously the example you gave was abstracted, but in my opinion the answer is a hard "no," it's not good form to reference a potentially undeclared variable - if for some reason an error is encountered in the `try:` before `x = 5`, then you are going to get an error when you try to `print(f"x = {x}")`.

More to the point, *why oh why* would the variable be assigned in the try block? I would say a good rule of thumb is to **only include in `try` that portion of the code you are actually testing for exceptions**.

Side-notes:

- I have been previously advised on SO that it's bad form to use a `except Exception`, because what you really should be doing is handling a certain `type` of error, or better yet a `particular` error (eg. `except IndexError`, which will result in all other types of errors being unhandled)... `try / except` is something that can easily introduce difficult to diagnose bugs if it's used non-specifically.
- I'm pretty sure `except:` and `except Exception` are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like these, **if there is a common execution path after the exception**, I usually do something like this (which has a certain `if/else`-ish touch to it as far as assignment to the variable is concerned):

```
try:
    price = get_min_price(product)
except Exception as ex:
    print("could not get price for product {}: {}".format(product, ex))
    price = 1000000.0
print(f"price = {price}")
if price <= min_price:
    send_price_alert(user, product, price)
```

However, more often than not, I structure my code in a way that whatever variables are filled in the `try` block, I won't be using after the `except` block:

```
try:
    price = get_min_price(product)
    print(f"price = {price}")
    if price <= min_price:
        send_price_alert(user, product, price)
except Exception as ex:
    print("could not get price for product {}: {}".format(product, ex))
```

Here, `price` isn't used after the `except` keyword, thus obviating the need for initialization.